# NSButton- border shown on click

Tags: cocoa, border, nsbutton, macos

In a Mac application, i'm using an NSButton with Gradient style ,no border and a custom image as its background.The problem is, on click of the button, a rectangular white area around the button is visible.How is it possible to not show that?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Answer (score 4):

You need to change button's type to ***Momentary Change***. You can change it in Attributes inspector:

[image: how to do it]

Or change programatically:

```
[button setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting `NSChangeGrayCellMask` or `NSChangeBackgroundCellMask` for `-setHighlightsBy:` or `-setShowsStateBy:`, try setting those to 0 instead, or not setting them.

Answer (score 0):

In your IB Attribute inspector set type of your button to 'Toggle'